# How to create a relationship between a table in a database and content type in views d7?

Tags: 7, views

A table table_A is present in database with a abc_nid and abc_code columns.
I have  a node having abc_nid as node_nid 
How can I link a abc_code (from the table_A) in a view using relationship(non programmatically) or any other way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly implement this functionality by creating a views plugin:

1. In your `<module_name>.module` file implement [`hook_views_api()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7).
2. In your `<module_name>.views.inc`, implement [`hook_views_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7). Something roughly like this:

   ```
   /** This hook should be placed in MODULENAME.views.inc and it will be
    * auto-loaded. MODULENAME.views.inc must be in the directory specified by the
    * 'path' key returned by MODULENAME_views_api(), or the same directory as the
    * .module file, if 'path' is unspecified.
    */
   function MODULENAME_views_views_data() {
     $data = array();

     // Select/Create a category.
     $data['table_A']['table']['group'] = t('Your category');

     // Define the join with your table.
     $data['table_A']['table']['join'] = array(
         'node' => array(
         'left_field' => 'abc_nid',
         'field' => 'nid',
       ),
     );

     $data['table_A']['abc_code'] = array(
       'title' => t('ABC Code title'),
       'help' => t('Some help text.'),
       'field' => array(
         'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
       ),
       'filter' => array(
         'handler' => 'views_handler_filter',
       ),
       'sort' => array(
         'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
       ),
     );
     return $data;
   }
   ```

   You can choose the appropriate handlers:

   - [Views field handlers](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers!views_handler_field.inc/group/views_field_handlers/7)
   - [Views sort handlers](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers%21views_handler_sort.inc/group/views_sort_handlers/7)
   - [Views filter handlers](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers%21views_handler_filter.inc/group/views_filter_handlers/7)

   If required you can add you own handlers by extending the handlers. But, adding a handler is **required**.
3. This will provide you a *field*, a *filter* and a *sort criteria* in your view of nodes which will *display/filter/sort* the fields on the basis of the value of `abc_code` for that particular field.

Comment: @harshal please see the edit. To find the comments

Comment: Where should I check for in the UI of the view ? I have written the code and caches cleared but not able to see it in the views ?

Comment: @harshal : You'll find it when you add a field, when you are creating a view to display fields of nodes. Make sure to replace the appropriate values of the table name and the column name.

Comment: If the handler is not included then will the code work ?

Comment: @harshal Nope. You'll have to add the handlers in order to use the code. See the edit

Comment: Now I am able to get the new group with the fields but when I add it I get an empty column values ? So is it due to 'not adding a handler'

Comment: If you are getting an option to add a field, and you get an empty column, that might mean that you don't have any value in the database table against that `nid`.

Comment: No I have data for that nid .. It is not bcoz database is having empty value .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10737/discussion-between-ajit-s-and-harshal)